# Only on submit send data to datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have datatable which I set as follows.On the page load the datagrid is showing as processing but I have not set it to be on load.

```
var oTable = $('#dataGrid').dataTable({
                    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                    "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0,1 ] }],
                        "processing": true,
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "ajax": "getReport.php",
                        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                $.ajax( {
                    "dataType": 'json', 
                    "type": "POST", 
                    "url": "getReport.php", 
                    "data": 'val1=' + $("value1").val()+'&val2=' + $("value2").val(), 
                    "success": fnCallback
                } );
                        }         
                      });



 $("#submit").click(function(){
                        oTable.fnReloadAjax();
                     });
```

I am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: oTable.fnReloadAjax is not a function`. I want the datatable only populate when the submit button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very clear - the function `fnReloadAjax` does not exist. What you need to call instead is `oTable.ajax.reload();` [See documentation here.](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

Comment: @lcarus ok I tried I had undefined error then I tried this  oTable.api().ajax.reload(); it does not have any error but not calling the ajax page either or anything on the datatable ?

Comment: @user8012596 if you can set up a fiddle and share it here I might be able to help you further. With just the information on your question is going to be very difficult to figure out the problem. `http://jsfiddle.net`

Comment: @lcarus but in the jsfiddle how to simulate my ajax calling ? Is it possible in that ?

Comment: @user8012596 is possible if your `getReport.php` page is public and requires no authentication but it doesn't matter. You can simulate the call specifying a location to a public page that returns a JSON array. The important thing is to verify that the call is being made. For example, replace  `"success": fnCallback` with `"success": function(){alert('called!);}`

Comment: @lcarus each calling will be different 'val1=' + $("value1").val()+'&val2=' + $("value2").val(),  so I dont think just a mere refresh will work right?

Comment: @lcarus on confirm there is no alert meaning its not calling that function then? I have even tried to remove this line "ajax": "getReportJourney.php",
          still the same though

Comment: @user8012596 doesn't look like it's calling it, at least is not returning a success; otherwise, the alert message would have popped up because that's what's supposed to do. Again, it's going to be very difficult to troubleshoot this. Try creating a very simple example using jsfiddle and go from there. If you are stuck on the example, post the question here again. Once you have the fiddle working; you ought to be able to translate it to your real scenario.

Comment: It *do* exists as a plugin [**fnReloadAjax**](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnReloadAjax)

Comment: @lcarus do you think any thing wrong here "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) { ? or  "data": 'val1=' + $("value1").val()+'&val2=' + $("value2").val(), ?

Comment: @davidkonrad thanks! never heard of it before but it seems to have been deprecated long time ago. @user8012596 are you using that plugin? did you include `//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/api/fnReloadAjax.js` in your script includes?

Comment: @lcarus no I dont have this script but I check my datatable version is  DataTables 1.10.12 but why is not recognizing this function  oTable.ajax.reload(); but the older version  oTable.api().ajax.reload();

Comment: @lcarus should I include this fnReloadAjax.js ?

Comment: @lcarus I have included the fnReloadAjax.js too but still its not calling the "fnServerData":  because now I am calling oTable.fnReloadAjax();